# Width of a table cell that contains elements with style="display:none;"

Tags: html, jquery-ui, styles

I have a table with a column that contains an image that I toggle with jQuery.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img class="tp" widht="24" height="23" src="1.png" />
      <img class="tp" widht="24" height="23" src="2.png" style="display:none;" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When the page is rendered, the table cell width is doubled.

I thought that when an element has `display:none` that didn't counted when the width of the table cell was calculated.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: do you have the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) demo?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: [demo](http://jsbin.com/ejulum/1/edit)

Comment: `widht`is it a typing mistake or a code mistake? It should be `width`

Comment: Fixing the typo still [does not reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/ejulum/3/edit).

Answer (score 0):

style="display: none" doesn't count on adding height or width of an element.

The width spelling is mismatched. This might have caused problem in yours :D

Answer (score 0):

It is **width** and not **widht** as you have typed.